# Do I have Disadvantage attacking with an off-hand weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, advantage-and-disadvantage, two-weapon-fighting

I'm pretty new to D&D and have a question. I am currently playing as a rogue swashbuckler (lvl 3) which encourages dual wielding. I love this mechanic and enjoy playing it so far but I'm confused about the bonus action part of it. I understand you don't add bonuses in most circumstances to the off-hand attack (sneak attack being an exception).

However, my DM tells me whenever I attack with my offhand I need to roll twice and take the lower of the two because I have a disadvantage with my offhand (which is also my bonus action). I can't find anything that says I need to do this. If this is how it works? Is there any way I can get rid of having a disadvantage with my off-hand? Or is this just a DM choice?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This seems to be a houserule created by your DM. By the rules, you don't have Disadvantage on attacks with your off-hand weapon, you just don't add your ability modifier to the damage it deals. And, unless you have a feat or ability saying otherwise, both weapons you're using must be Light weapons, limiting the size of weapons you can use with it.

You might want to ask your DM why they introduced this extra rule, or why they think this is the normal way to play.

Comment: In the GM's defense, earlier editions did sometimes implement maluses to attacks made with a second weapons. 2e, for instance, gave a -2 to the "main" weapon and -4 to the secondary weapon on attack rolls.

Comment: It's also worth noting that two-weapon fighting in general is already very weak (low damage for the cost of a bonus action) for basically anyone except rogues, for whom it's a second chance to get Sneak Attack, and this house-rule would make it even less appealing.

Comment: @V2Blast And of course, disadvantage would prevent them from being able to Sneak Attack with their off-hand, which makes it even *less* appealing for them.